# Why is empty data being transmitted when sending an ajax request to jquery post?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<head>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="all-comments"></div>
    <input type="hidden" name="page_id" value="1">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            let page_id = $('input[name="page_id"]').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'vender/show_comment.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    page_id: page_id
                }
            });
            setTimeout(function() {
                $("#all-comments").load("vender/show_comment.php")
            }, 1000);
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

show_comment.php

```
<?php

$page_id=$_POST['page_id'];
 if(empty($page_id))
 $str="I'm empty";
 else
 $str=$page_id; 
?>
<div class="new-comment">
    <p><?php echo $str?></p>
    <p><?php echo $str?></p>
</div>
```

I take data from input and pass it through ajax, as a result, I get "I'm empty". Why doesn't it output the input value?

Although when I receive the same data by pressing the button and send them to the server, they will not be empty. But I need to do a data offset when the page loads

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to wait for the response:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: 'vender/show_comment.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { 'page_id' : page_id },
            success: function(response) {
            $("#all-comments").html(response);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks.I thought I had to wait for the execution somehow, but I didn't understand how

Answer (score 1):

You are making **two** different requests.

---

The **first** request is a POST request, with a payload, but you **ignore** the response.

```js
            $.ajax({
                url: 'vender/show_comment.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    page_id: page_id
                }
            });
```

---

The **second** request is a GET request, without a payload, and you drop the response into the all-comments element.

```js
            $("#all-comments").load("vender/show_comment.php")
```

---

You haven't done anything to persist the data between two requests.

You could **remove the `$.ajax` call entirely** and make your `load` call a POST request and include the data there:

```js
$("#all-comments").load("vender/show_comment.php", { page_id })
```

The data still won't be persisted for subsequent GET requests which is generally a desirable feature of comment systems.

To do that you'll need to store the data somewhere (a database is the usual choice) and then retrieve it in subsequent requests.

Rough pseudo-code would look something along the lines of:

```
if IS POST REQUEST
    if DATA IS NOT VALID
        respond with error
    else
        insert data into database
get data from database
generate html
respond with html
```